# Combine two pandas Series with overlap into one column

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say I have two Pandas series A and B that I wish to combine into one series. I want to set the values of overlapping rows to 0 (or some other arbitrary value).

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
Name: A, dtype: int64

2    2
3    2
4    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Into

```
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    2
4    2
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

How would I go about doing this in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `concat` then check the dup index , drop `reindex` back

```
s = pd.concat([a,b])
s = s[~s.index.duplicated(keep=False)].reindex(s.index.unique(),fill_value=0)
out
Out[189]: 
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    2
4    2
dtype: int64
```